# HUGE ammount of duplicate files in this directory

Tags: windows-sbs-2011, deduplication, files

I maintain our companies SBS2011 server, and I have duplicate file reports emailed to me on a monthly basis. I've noticed an increasing build up of duplicated files in the following directories:

NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller

BUILTIN\Administrators

S-1-5-21-253125893-3659723687-2658493243-1156

NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

What are these directories, and can any of these duplicate files be removed safely without causing any problems?

Thanks for any ideas/info!

Comment: I hope this tool helps you "DuplicateFilesDeleter". Google it and try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huh?  Those "directories" are actually security principals, probably the owners of the files.  They aren't directories at all.

Given that, check and see if the dupe files are actually all in the same directories, or if these just look odd because of so many files having the same owners?

Comment: I see, i looked further into where these duplicate files are located, and it seems a majority of them are simply exchange logs and VSS snapshots created by our backup program. A simply misunderstanding on my part :-) Thanks for pointing this out, as it has solved the issue of my uncertanty!